# Javascript date formatting

Tags: javascript, date, datepicker

I've tried my level best but couldn't get the result. What I need is the date in YYYY-MM-DD format. Here is my current code:

> ```
> function AddDays(days) {
>
>             var thisDate = new Date();
>             thisDate.setDate(thisDate.getDate() + days);
>             var dd = ( thisDate.getFullYear() + '-' + (thisDate.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + thisDate.getDate() );
>             return dd;
>
>         }
>
>         alert(AddDays(365));
> ```

I'm getting "2014-8-7" as result but I want to get it as YYYY-MM-DD. I need it to look like "2014-08-07".

Comment: Duplicate of many similar questions. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17996874/leading-0-missing-from-data-and-time

Comment: @Eugene, that's a jQuery question, though. This one is about JavaScript.

Comment: Yes, just typing that. Sorry.

Comment: There has already been a question on this:-

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066586/get-string-in-yyyymmdd-format-from-js-date-object

Comment: You need a zerofill function: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1267338/358906

Comment: @dystroy i checked every question and then posted this. this is unique one and i need users help, not irrelevant report from everyone here.

Comment: @MohamedFawaskhan no, this is exactly the same than the question I linked to, where there are answers explaining how to add the leading 0.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if the date or month is under 10, if it is, add "0" before the date/month:

```
function AddDays(days) {

        var dateObject = new Date();
        dateObject.setDate(new Date().getDate() + days);
        var year = dateObject.getFullYear();
        var month = dateObject.getMonth()+1 < 10 ? "0" + (dateObject.getMonth()+1) : dateObject.getMonth()+1;
        var date = dateObject.getDate() < 10 ? "0" + dateObject.getDate() : dateObject.getDate();
        return year + "-" + month + "-" + date;

}

alert(AddDays(365));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var today = new Date();
console.log(today.getFullYear()+'-'+((today.getMonth()+1>9)?today.getMonth():'0'+(today.getMonth()+1))+'-'+(today.getDate()<10?'0'+today.getDate():today.getDate()));
```

Fiddle for this:-
http://jsfiddle.net/Ge4cw/

It has also been previously asked:-

[Get String in YYYYMMDD format from JS date object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066586/get-string-in-yyyymmdd-format-from-js-date-object)

Answer (score 0):

```
function AddDays(days) {

            var thisDate = new Date();
            thisDate.setDate(thisDate.getDate() + days);
            return thisDate;

        }

alert(getReadableDate(AddDays(365)));


function getReadableDate(date) {
        return [date.getFullYear(), fillZeroes(date.getMonth() + 1), fillZeroes(date.getDate())].join('-');

        function fillZeroes(text) {
            return (new Array(2 - (text || '').toString().length + 1)).join('0') + (text || '');
        }
    }
```

Comment: You make it much more complex than necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I faced that problem once. My solution was to pass by a function who add zero if necessary:

```
function addZero(date)
{
    if (date < 10)
       return "0"+date;
   return date;
}
```

or smaller :

```
function addZero(date)
{
    return (date < 10)? "0"+date : date;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript/10685571#10685571)

I think this answer should help you.

thisDate.getMonth() and thisDate.getDate() return an integer, which may have only one digit.
You should transform it to string to add the "0":

Example

```
var m = thisDate.getMonth()+1; // One digit month
m = '' + (m<=9 ? '0' + m : m); // Two digit month
```

Answer (score 0):

This works everytime:

```
var now = new Date();
var day = ("0" + now.getDate()).slice(-2);
var month = ("0" + (now.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
var today = now.getFullYear() + "-" + (month) + "-" + (day);
alert(today);
```

Answer (score -1):

you need this:

```
function AddDays(days) {

            var thisDate = new Date();
            thisDate.setDate(thisDate.getDate() + days);
            var dd = ( thisDate.getFullYear() + '-' + ("0"+ (thisDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '-' + ( "0" + thisDate.getDate()).slice(-2) );
            return dd.toString('yyyy-MM-DD');;
        }
        alert(AddDays(365));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w9fxr/1/

check again my dear friend it will handle all month single and double digit all

Comment: You'll get 2013-012-06 with this.

Answer (score -1):

Just for an Idea, Explained clearly

http://blog.justin.kelly.org.au/simple-javascript-function-to-format-the-date-as-yyyy-mm-dd/

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
var thisDate = new Date();

alert(thisDate.getFullYear() + '-' + ("0" + (thisDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '-' + ("0" + (thisDate.getDate() + 1)).slice(-2));
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k2R2s/)