# To convert in specific Time Format

Tags: jquery, time

how to convert  Time  format H:MM to HH:mm format if it is showing in single digit. For example I want to show 9:00  AM as 09:00 AM.

My input should be 9:00 AM and output should be 09:00 AM.

Comment: JavaScript's [`Date()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) might be of value.

Comment: For that you should start writing some code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Leading 0 missing from data and time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17996874/leading-0-missing-from-data-and-time)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var newDate = new Date();  
console.log("0" + newDate.getHours());
```

Use `Date()`. It might help you.

Comment: I am not using Date().  I am receiving string data like 12:10 AM from service call and have to convert in specific format.

Answer (score 0):

Moment.js (https://momentjs.com/) is normally my go-to library for Date parsing.

Not sure exactly what your output format is in full, but something like the following should do the trick:

```
moment("1/5/15 9:3:4", "D/M/YY h:m:s").format("DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss") == "01/05/2015 09:03:04"
```